# NoClassDefFoundError for XMLGregorianCalendar in Java

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, jaxb

I am using Java6,Apache Tomcat and Jersey RESTful. While unmarshelling the XML to JAXB, I am getting the following exception.Can any body help me on this ?
Note: This Exception is inconsistent.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/jaxp/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendarImpl$Parser
     at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl.newXMLGregorianCalendar(Unknown Source)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$13.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:543)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$13.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:517)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor$CompositeTransducedAccessorImpl.parse(TransducedAccessor.java:241)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.LeafPropertyLoader.text(LeafPropertyLoader.java:61)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.text(UnmarshallingContext.java:462)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.processText(StAXStreamConnector.java:367)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.handleEndElement(StAXStreamConnector.java:245)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:214)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:358)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.BridgeImpl.unmarshal(BridgeImpl.java:120)
     at com.sun.xml.bind.api.Bridge.unmarshal(Bridge.java:233)
     at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointArgumentsBuilder$DocLit.readRequest(EndpointArgumentsBuilder.java:517)
     at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointArgumentsBuilder$Composite.readRequest(EndpointArgumentsBuilder.java:188)
     at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.invoke(EndpointMethodHandler.java:243)
     at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:93)
     at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:598)
     at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:557)
     at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:542)
     at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:439)
     at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:243)
     at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:444)
     at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:244)
     at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:134)
     at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$AuthorizedInvoke.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:272)
     at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter.post(HttpServletAdapter.java:185)
     at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.doPost(JAXWSServlet.java:180)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
     at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.service(JAXWSServlet.java:64)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
     at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
     at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
     at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
     at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)
     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3498)
     at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
     at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source)
     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2180)
     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2086)
     at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1406)
     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have, you been adding [xerces jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xerces/xercesImpl/2.11.0) in your classpath ?
If not download it from [xerces jar link](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/xerces/xercesImpl/2.11.0/xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar) and add it to your project classpath.

Give me feedback please. enjoy :)

Comment: We are using Xercus in Class path as this jar is one of the Maven Dependent . I know this problem arises when we have Xercus jar in ClassPath. Idealy , we should not use this jar in ClassPath as this Jar comes with JDK. My Question now is, How can we avoid this ?

Comment: Did you get an answer for this @SKC... ?

Answer (score 3):

**EXPLANATION:** New versions of java have xerces lib in jdk. This lib conflict with apache's xerses lib. 
Even when it says "no class" it's because there are two of them. 
**SOLUTION:** Check if this is true for your project and remove one of them from the dependencies and build the project.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to multiple xercesImpl.jar in class path. This jar may be from your application, from JDK and from servlet container. Following changes in POM resolved this issue for me.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>resolver</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>serializer</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>xerces</groupId>
      <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```